# What does `:location => ...` and `head :ok` mean in the 'respond_to' format statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, format, respond-to

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to know what the `:location => ...` and `head :ok` statements mean in following code, how they work and how I can\should use those.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
end

respond_to do |format|
    format.xml  { head :ok }
end
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

1. `render ... :location => @user` will set the [HTTP location header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) to inform the client of the location of the newly created resource (that is, its URL)
2. [`head :ok` sets `render` to return an empty response (so just the header, no body) with status 200.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-head-to-build-header-only-responses)  `head :ok` is shorthand for `render nothing: true, status: :ok`.
   [Here's a list of all the `:status` options you can use for setting the appropriate status code.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option)

Comment: so what does the client do with the newly created user location?

Comment: @highBandWidth Well whatever they want to do. Precise semantics of "location of a newly-created resource" depends on application. In the example above such URL can be used to show/edit user profile.

Comment: @hoha I am using url in location, along with head :ok, that needs a parameter. But i get the parameter's value as undefined.

    id = comment.assignment.id
    head :ok, location: assignment_lessons_path(id)

Could you please help me here? Thanks. :)