# Rendering json versus js in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting different results if I render js versus render json .Trying to figure out why this doesn't work quite as expected

My javascript looks like this:

```
$( function () {
    $('.delete_post').bind('ajax:success', function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
        }
    )
});
```

Controller:

**Works**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :nothing => true}
end
```

**Works**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { head :ok }
end
```

**Works**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => {} }
end
```

**Doesn't work**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { head :ok }
end
```

**Doesn't work**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :nothing => true }
end
```

When I examine what is happening in the ajax response I see that the cases where it doesn't work I get a "parseError".

I understand that the Content-type getting sent back is different (text/javascript vs applicaiton/json), but I would still expect the last 2 cases to work since they are sending back a 200 to the server.

(Code derived from: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/)

Comment: You may find this helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213956/what-means-location-and-head-ok-in-the-respond-to-format-statemen

Comment: That link is helpful, but just explains why/how to send a 200 response.  I know that I am sending a 200 response in the "Doesn't work" cases, but still getting into a "parseError" within the javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
format.json { head :ok }
```

and

```
format.json { render :nothing => true }
```

don't work because they're not returning valid json. `head :ok` will simply set the response header to 200 and `:nothing => true` will render a blank page/document which not valid json.